# NLTK error not show some word

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

```
word_list = "love does not make the world go round. love is what makes the ride worthwhile" 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
for word in word_list:
    #print word
    if word in stopwords.words('english'):
       #print word #print out stopword for checking
       word_list.remove(word)
    else:
       print word
```

for example...In my word_list...I have "love does not make the world go round. love is what makes the ride worthwhile"

I want to print out all word that not in stop word...

but it print out only love, make, go, round, love, makes, worthwhile.......Word "world, ride" is not print out..Anyone know how to solve it? Thank you...

Comment: Why don't you post the code that you're currently using, along with what you want your code to do and what your code is currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `word_list`, so that it is a list of words, it works fine. `word_list` will contain the words you are after.

```
word_list = ['love','does','not','make','the','world','go','round','love',
             'is','what','makes','the','ride','worthwhile']
#your code: 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
for word in word_list:
    #print word
    if word in stopwords.words('english'):
       #print word #print out stopword for checking
       word_list.remove(word)
    else:
       print word   
#now put:
print word_list
#output:
['love', 'not', 'make', 'world', 'go', 'round', 'love', 'what',
 'makes', 'ride', 'worthwhile']
```

Comment: sorry where you put "print word_list" for getting those result? Mine still not work as it till not show "world, ride"...

Comment: @ThanaDaray - I've put your code in, to show you how it fits. How many spaces are before lines of code controls the logical structure of the code, its very important to understand this, it might be worth your while having a look at some python tutorials on this. Anyway, I hope it works for you know :)